# How to get continuous lines in ggplot2 with discontinuous dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

When missing data is present or there is a large gap in the dates, ggplot produces a discontinuous line.

Eg:

[image]

```
    q.data<-structure(list(date = structure(c(15544, 15546, 15547, 15548, 
15550, 15552, 15554, 15556, 15575, 15580, 15587, 15588, 15589, 
15593, 15596), class = "Date"), data = c(NA, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 
0.7, 0.8, 0.9, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1.1, 1.7, 2)), .Names = c("date", 
"data"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

q.data$date<-as.Date(q.data$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")

q.plot<-qplot(data=q.data,
              x=date,
              y=data)+geom_line()

print(q.plot)
```

I am looking for a way to force a continuous line.

Comment: Ben Bolker indicated that this is a problem with NAs and is resolved by their removal.  However, I have many variables/columns with NAs appearing at different time points, which precludes the use of na.omit on my data as whole.

Comment: Something along the lines of a stat_omit would be great for this.

Comment: I started to try to hack `stat_identity` into `stat_omit` (i.e., make `stat_omit` just a wrapper around `stat_identity`), but I didn't get very far ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it really happens with a large gap in the dates, *in the absence of `NA`s*. The `NA` values seem to be  your problem.

I think

```
q.plot <- qplot(data=na.omit(q.data),...)
```

should work, but what I tried (which worked) was

```
print(q.plot %+% na.omit(q.data))
```

[image]

PS: 1. it would be slightly nicer to use `dput` to post your data. 2. My solution also gets rid of `NA` values at the beginning and end of the series, which could conceivably be problematic ...

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, with record speed!  It is true that the NAs seem to be the problem, however, as I have many variable I wish to plot in the same way, with NAs appearing at different time point for each variable, this solution would be awkward, as it would either remove all rows with NAs or would have to be done individually for each variable to be plotted.  Sorry I did not specify this in my question.